# Scala/Twirl variables and scope/defining

Tags: scala, twirl

I'm a front ender by trade but I've been asked to hop on to a Scala project which leverages the Play framework so includes Twirl.  I'm trying to create a template which displays slightly different outputs depending on the string which is passed in.

Here is my code:

```
@(status: String)(implicit messages: Messages)

@{
    if(status == "00") {
        val pageTitle = "Page title"
        val appStatus = "className"
        val title = "message"
        val subTitle = "message"
        val step1Status = "className"
        val step2Status = "className"
        val step3Status = "className"
        val image1 = "/customs/assets/images/image.png"
        val image2 = "/customs/assets/images/image.png"
        val image3 = "/customs/assets/images/image.png"
        val optionalHeading = ""
        val optionalParagraph = ""
        val listContents = "<li>@Messages('message')</li><li>@Messages('message')</li>"
        val optionalLink = "<br /><a class='button' href='@routes.DashboardController.display(custom)' role='button'>@Messages('message')</a>"
    }

    if(status == "01") {
        //Other variables
    }
    if(status == "04") {
        //Etc...
    }
}

@layout(${pageTitle}) {
        <div class="content__body">
            <div class="hero">
                <div class="${appStatus}">
                    <h1 class="bold-large">@Messages(${title})</h1>
                    <p>
                        ${afterSubTitle}
                    </p>
                    <ol class="appstatus-steps">
                        <li><span class="${step1Status}"><img alt="Complete" title="Complete" src=" + ${image1} + ">@Messages("messages.Received")</span></li>
                        <li><span class="${step2Status}"><img alt="Complete" title="Complete" src=" + ${image2} + ">@Messages("messages.Processing")</span></li>
                        <li><span class="${step3Status}"><img alt="Complete" title="Complete" src=" + ${image3} + ">@Messages("messages.Decision")</span></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

            ${optionalHeading}
            ${optionalParagraph}

            <h2>@Messages("messages.next")</h2>

            <ul class="list list-bullet">
                ${listContents}
            </ul>

            ${optionalLink}
        </div>
    }
```

So, as you can see, the idea is that this page is called with a code (status) and based on that string, a number of variables are defined which alter the way the page is formed; content/css classes/images etc.

This doesn't work (you may be surprised to learn!)

It's really unclear to me WHY it doesn't though.  I thought that you accessed variables using a ${Variable} format, but it's possible that you're supposed to use the @Variable format instead.

Even when I try to change them to the @Variable way, I'm still getting problems and I loosely understand that this is to do with scope in Scala/Twirl and there's a "defining" keyword which can be used.  I've read some documentation but I'm not getting it.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT**

Okay, let's just consider the below code instead:

```
@(status: String)(implicit messages: Messages)

@{
    if(status == "00") {
        val myClass = "custom-class-1"
    }
    if (status == "01") {
        val myClass = "custom-class-2"
    }
@layout("page title") {
    <div class="@myClass">This is a div</div>
}
```

So 'all I want to do' :) is be able to define a variety of variables based on the status and then use those variables in the template of the page.

Does that make sense?  I'm so new to Scala so Tuples/Defining is lost on me at the moment, but I am learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @pedrorijio is almost exactly correct, but the actual code which worked for me in the end was this:

```
@myClass = @{status match {
  case "00" => "custom-class-1"
  case "01" => "custom-class-2"
}}
```

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Oh, small mistake :) twirl always has some tricks, should have tried on intellij :p

Comment: Ah! Is it a Twirl thing?  I wondered if that was the case - couldn't have sorted it without you though so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be more used to javascript variables and scopes :)

In Scala and Twirl, if you only define a variable (in this case it's a value because it's immutable) inside an if statement, the value is only accessible inside the if block

One solution could be to have the if statement to return a tuple with all the variables, and use the power of assignment operation, like:

```
val (myA, myB, myC) = if(something) {
 val a = "a"
 val b = "b"
 val c = "c"

 (a,b,c) // this will return the 3 variables/values because if statements are an expression, and expressions return something
} else {
 val a = "A"
 val b = "B"
 val c = "C"

 (a,b,c)
}

// now you have a,b,c defined in this scope and you can do whatever you need with them
```

if you want to return different variables depending on the if statement, you will have more complications. a solution would be to make the not needed variables `null` or an `Option`

Let me know if you need anything else better explained :)

> **EDIT**: solution for minified edited example

I don't have anything here to check if it compiles, but it should be something like:

```
@(status: String)(implicit messages: Messages)

@{
    val myClass = if(status == "00") {
        "custom-class-1"
    } else if (status == "01") {
        "custom-class-2"
    } else {
      ""
    }

@layout("page title") {
    <div class="@myClass">This is a div</div>
}
```

**Alternative** using pattern matching:

replace the if/else statement with:

```
val myClass = status match {
          case "00" => "custom-class-1"
          case "01" => "custom-class-2"
          case _ => ""
        }
```

(the `case _` is like "in every other case")

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely right, JS is much more my thing!  I've edited my original post with a much smaller code snippet.  Would you be able to provide a worked solution to that so I can see a pattern of how to format my code?

Comment: just did @SonyaBaled :)

Comment: Okay - I've given this a go, but I'm getting the same issue as I had before: the 'myClass' value isn't being found. I thought that this was to do with scoping inside of if statements in Scala, but I could be totally wrong as I'm so new to this! Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked which value the status holds?

Comment: I know for sure the status holds '00', so it should give me back a variable called myClass with the value 'custom-class-1'.  However, the variable myClass cannot be found when I try and call it...

Comment: Okay, I got it! Thanks to @pedririjio - it was very similar to the solution he posted.  I answered my own question to include the code I actually used.